# How to dynamically inject a service from a lazy loaded module in Angular 9+ without components?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-services, angular-injector

I am attempting to access an instance of a service from a lazy loaded module from within a component. The module does not have any components to use for constructor-based injection. The Angular documentation was not helpful and all the various tutorials I found on Medium and similar sites were not applicable.

Here is the code from the component doing the lazy load of the service.

```js
await import ('./lazy.module')
  .then(module => module.LazyModule)
  .then(module => {return module;})
  .then(module => this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module))
  .then(factory => {
    let module = factory.create(this.injector);
    this.lazyService = module.injector.get(LazyService);
  });
```

The problem is that including LazyService in the current component will defeat the purpose of lazy loading and the get() method seems to want a type only creating a chicken in egg problem for this approach. I looked into InjectionToken as another option but it wants a generic definition which again requires import of the LazyService.

Can anyone explain how lazy service loading is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found an approach and it appears to be working around Angular deficiencies rather than being a basic Angular capability.

The idea is to add the reference to the service in the module definition. In my case, I stored the service reference in a static variable called 'entrySet' added to the module definition. The 'lazyService' variable is just a variable of type 'any' added to the component that wants to lazy load the service.

So here is the update of the code posted before to retrieve the service:

```
    await import( './lazy.module' )
        .then( module => module.LazyModule )
        .then( module => {
            this.lazyService = module.entrySet.lazyService;
            return module;
        })
        .then( module => this.compiler.compileModuleAsync( module ) )
        .then( factory => {
            let module = factory.create( this.injector );
            this.lazyService = module.injector.get( this.lazyService );
        });
```

And here in the export block below is the relevant code of the LazyModule to make the service available:

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [],
    declarations: []
    imports:
    [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers:
    [
        LazyService 
    ]
})
export class SnapshotManagerModule
{
    static entrySet = {
        lazyService: LazyService
    };  
}
```

I figured this out with the help of content from this article (https://medium.com/@ebrehault_25985/angular-9-makes-lazy-loading-without-routing-so-easy-18774092ed34)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to lazy-load the service class to pass to `injector.get()`. To do this without creating two separate chunks for the service and module, I created a barrel that exports them both, like this:

```
// lazy-barrel.ts
export { LazyModule } from './lazy.module';
export { LazyService } from './lazy.service';
```

Then to use it:

```
const { LazyModule, LazyService } = await import('./lazy-barrel');
const moduleRef = createNgModuleRef(LazyModule, this.injector);
const service = moduleRef.injector.get(LazyService);
```